# Генерация админки для сайта на asp.net mvc4, ms sql server, entity framework, jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

Есть ли быстрый способ сгенерировать админку (хотя бы каркас) из модели? Технология приведена в заголовке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, с помощью Visual Studio можно делать шаблонные контроллеры (Scaffolding). Этот способ позволяет сгенерировать CRUD операции для произвольной сущности из EF.

Comment: Как? Расширьте ответ.